# Fix buttons at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, list

I am a beginner in Android programming. I want to build a simple application with a main list view in the screen and two buttons at the bottom of the screen.

When more items are added to the list view, the list view should scroll without increasing the overall length of the list view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of a list view : http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

As for the two buttons at the bottom you can use **addFooterView(View)**

You can also use buttons as explained here : [How to create fixed footer in android layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318775/how-to-create-fixed-footer-in-android-layout).

Comment: Thank you. The layout editor seems difficult to use. Modifying the XML directly is easier.