# Android: How to add a submit button at the bottom of the list view

Tags: android, android-layout

My list view contains a checkbox for each row,
I need to submit the selected items to another activity. I tried to add a `<Button>` after `<ListView>` but it is not appearing at all.
How to add a submit button at the bottom of the list view, that should appear even if we scroll the list?

Comment: Hi Balu, can you plz provide your comments

Answer (score 1):

One way is Adding a footer view to your Listview and have a button in the footer.

Comment: Hi @Sat, 
by using footer view, im getting the button at the end of the list view, and is visible only if i scroll down to bottom of the entire list view. I want it to be displayed constantly at the bottom of the screen, even with/without scrolling of the list

Comment: Add a fixed layout at the bottom as footer , instead of using footerview of listview, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318775/how-to-create-fixed-footer-in-android-layout This post might help you.