# RelativeLayout views overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout

Desired layout is a header, with two frames below (to contain fragments later) and buttons fixed at the bottom of the screen:

```
     Header Text     
----------------------
frame 1   |  frame 2
----------------------
btn 1   btn 2   btn 3
```

I pretty much have this sorted (xml at end), with one problem... the two frames are overlapping the buttons.

I've done some searching on the issue and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318775/how-to-create-fixed-footer-in-android-layout), but all that does is change my problem from the frames overflowing the buttons to the frames overflowing the header.

I also tried setting the buttons to appear below the frames instead of aligned to the bottom of the parent, but that just pushed them off the screen.

current layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fdname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="No department info has been entered yet"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fdaddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/fdname"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="address"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/fdaddress"
            android:background="#ff23cf"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="2dip" />
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/frames"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/horizontalline"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/leftpane"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/verticalline"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ff23cf"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:paddingRight="5dip" />
            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rightpane"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
            </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/EventViewButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/menu_event_view"
                    android:textSize="15dp" 
                    android:layout_weight="1">
            </Button>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/MemberViewButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/menu_member_view"
                    android:textSize="15dp" 
                    android:layout_weight="1">
            </Button>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/AttendanceViewButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/menu_atnd_view"
                    android:textSize="15dp" 
                    android:layout_weight="1">
            </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/frames" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_below="@id/horizontalline" android:orientation="horizontal" >    Why is your layout_height="match_parent" for this? Shouldn't this be "wrap_content"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to declare the `LinearLayout` containing your buttons before the `LinearLayout` containing your frames, preserving the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` attribute.

Then, to your frames container, add an `above` constraint:

```
android:layout_below="@id/horizontalline"
android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
```

This way should force your frames to be last thing to be drawn on the screen, thus filling the remaining space.

Hope it works!

Comment: It sounded good, but I just tried it and I still have the issue with the frames overlapping the buttons.  Thanks for the effort.  If I figure it out I'll post my solution.

Comment: Ok, lesson learned.  Do *not* rely on the graphical layout to show you what will actually happen.  Once I applied code and actually got a view displayed in the frames, it looked and worked as it should (with the changes suggested by you in your answer).  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout             
    android:id="@+id/frames"             
    android:layout_width="match_parent"             
    android:layout_height="match_parent"             
    android:layout_below="@id/horizontalline"             
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Why is your layout_height="match_parent"?  You'll need to specify some height, or wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/layout/relative_layout_1.html

Refer to this for top layer/alignment of you three views.(three text views in example)

Then use linearlayout with orientation horizontal, for your two frames, and same again for buttons

--

so basically to the `frames` id add alignbottom true , and provide

```
android:layout_above
android:layout_below
```

parameters

Comment: Not understanding... I don't want the frames on the bottom, so why would I add the alignbottom to them?