# LinearLayout should fill minimum space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But if in first text view (that in LinearLayout) is a lot of text, second text view goes off the screen. This can be solved by setting android:layout_weigh="1" to linear layout. But in this case linear layout will fill all space, and I need that linear layout fill minimum space when in it short text, and not hiding second text view when in linear layout a lot of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first textview occupies too much horizontal space, the second textview is rendered outside the screen...

To avoid rendering the second textview outside the screen, you need to limit the horizontal size of the first textview. You could give the first textview an android:layout_width with a fixed numeric value. You could set android:singleLine to false. You could set android:maxWidth to an appropriate value. (I haven't tried these solutions, but they should work).

Alternatively, you may consider using a single textview instead of two in a row.

Comment: Thank's. I forgotten about android:maxWidth.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to put your first TextView in a ScrollView, and put your second TextView in a fixed footer which will never be hidden (this can be done [with a RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318775/how-to-create-fixed-footer-in-android-layout)).

If you have too much text in your first TextView then you will be able to scroll it while still showing the second TextView.

Comment: ScrollView is not suit for me. Second text view should always be shown. If in first text view a lot of text it must break into lines.